# Can we clean up answers on the question about passing data from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, clean-up

The question [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/3853934) currently has 15 answer, of which most either repeat what's already in other answers, or provide very poor solutions, which don't work in many cases.

- [Jessé Catrinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24834434/3853934), [Nishant Mendiratta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29612988/3853934) and [Yosra Nagati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620793/3853934) repeat what's in [Madara Uchiha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/3853934).
- [andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741482/3853934), [aequalsb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30312028/3853934), [Amit Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648718/3853934), [Tapasit Suesasiton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400425/3853934), [Niladri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460354/3853934), [qnimate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027575/3853934), [asdasd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23813274/3853934) and [Doberon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30672703/3853934) don't encode the data correctly.

Can we delete these answers?

Comment: A race for the SCITE! That's 44 upvote right ..

Comment: I don't know why some answers got upvotes. There is even [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript?answertab=votes#comment47381063_23813274)... The answers that you have posted in the first bullet are valid, so removing these isn't qualified. The answers in the second bullet ... yeah ... if you ensure that the data is secure then these works. But they need an additional info yes.